# Apache Server and SQL Server 2008 Express Performance. Isolate, method or suggestions

Tags: php, sql-server, performance, apache, debugging

I was wondering if some tips or guidance can be provided for the following issue.

Environment type: Small office, approx 20 users.
Network: All server, workstation belong to a single subnet
Infrastructure: Virtualised webserver and virtualised database server.

Currently I have a web server (Win7SP1 x64) running Apache 2.2.22 (Win32) and PHP 5.3.10. I have built some pages that connects to our database (SQL2k8 Express) and calls procedures, the procedures are basically just basic select statements with joins and conditions. Once the result set are returned, PHP loop through the result set, row by row and display the rows as it flow through.

What happens is that from time to time, the result page can take a extremely long to load,where no results set are displayed but the web browser loading bar/icon flashes. Some times it will just give a blank screen at the end of the load, which typically means the query connection has timed-out or some times it will return the result set. For example, under normal behaviour, a page will take approx 1-3s to load, while at odd times, it may take up to 20-30s.

I have noticed that if I run queries in SQLSVR Mgmt Studio, queries that may take ~5s to return a result set may take approx ~15s to load on my web server.

I know poor PHP coding can cause slow downs but the odd performance behaviour has me bit baffled, as Im sure my coding isnt that bad.

So if people could offer some tips in how I can go about diagnosting or isolating the problem, or advise areas that I could look at, it will be great. I know there are Apache logs, SQL SVR logs and performance indicators, but Im still fairly new to this area and am really lost in the approach /methodology I should take.

Example, any specific mods I should enable in Apache etc. or the type of Apache server I should use, connection sockets in web server etc?

Example of my PHP query/procedure calls

```
$queryStatement = "exec myProc @para1='asd'";
$prepare = $dbConnect->prepare($queryStatement);
$result = $prepare->execute();
WHILE($result = $prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
set_time_limit(180);
echo $result
}
```

Cheers everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you do some reading on how to approach SQL Server performance troubleshooting. The [Waits and Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) methodology is a good start, but if you're absolute beginner it may be a little bit too abstract. There is also [Troubleshooting Performance Problems in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) article, which is a more hands-on approach into identifying the bottleneck(s). The SQL Server Customer Advisory Team has put together a [Performance Troubleshooting Flowchart](http://sqlcat.com/files/folders/280/download.aspx) that can help. And there are many good books, like [Professional SQL Server 2008 Internals and Troubleshooting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470484284) or [Troubleshooting SQL Server - A Guide for the Accidental DBA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1906434786) (there are many more).

Some possible causes that would cause symptoms similar to what you describe:

- a bad query plan. Sometimes you get a good plan that executes in 1-2 seconds, but sometimes you get a bad plan that takes 30 seconds. This issue is discussed at length in [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) and investigation requires capturing and comparing execution plans. However, the symptoms would be that the problem page is responsive and then, all of the sudden, becomes unresponsive with 30 seconds load times, *stays unresponsive for a while*, then mysteriously becomes responsive again.
- lock contention on updates. This would mean that your reads are blocked behind writes waiting to commit. This would cause sporadic single-time, odd, unresponsive pages. But 30 seconds loads would imply a 30 second write, which is unlikely.
- Database growth events, specially log growth events. This one would cause exactly the symptoms you describe: odd, one time, unresponsive pages taking 30-40 seconds to load. Also, when this happens, *any* page on your site would take 30-40 seconds to load, and then they would all become again responsive. This is explained by your database files (Specially the log file) having to grow, and the 30-40 seconds is the time needed to expand the file and initialize it with zero-s. Fortunately this is very easy to investigate: the growth events are visible in performance counters [SQL Server, Databases Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189883(v=sql.100).aspx) **Log Growths**: Total number of times the transaction log for the database has been expanded. If this counter is non-zero fro your database, is likely the culprit. Data file growths unfortunately are not captured there, but they are captured in the [default trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175513.aspx) (the linked article shows how to read it). Note that log growths also reveal that you have a non-simple recovery model set and no log backups occur, your log may grow until it fills the entire disk... Easy to validate using [sys.database_files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397.aspx).

These are just some basic ideas barely skimming the surface of what you need to look at... unfortunately there is no silver bullet.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips and guidance! This has definitely given me areas to look into. Prior to this, truly I had no idea or what could be used. Cheers!

Of course, for everyone else, if you have other comments or tips, feel free. Cheers :)